# In a standard labor market signaling game, which weak Perfect-Bayesian equilibria (PBE) are actually sequential equilibria?

Tags: game-theory, bayesian-game, asymmetric-information, signaling

In a standard labor market signaling game with two types, the only "sensible" equilibria are the least-cost separating equilibria; as such these are the equilibria that survive a standard refinement of the weak PBE such as the [Cho and Kreps (1987)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1885060) intuitive criterion. However, sequential equilibrium (SE) is also a refinement of the PBE. Which pooling/separating/hybrid equilibria survive the refinement from PBE to SE?